# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I have a method which returns the date as "August 12, 2022" how can change that to datetime to concatenate with datetime.timedelta(days = 10)

```
def date_return():
    return date


date_return() + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
```

throws  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string into a datetime object. Python doesn't know any information about the date since it is a string.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('August 12, 2022', '%B %d, %Y')
datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 12, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('August 12, 2022', '%B %d, %Y') + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 22, 0, 0)
```

datetime string format codes for your date:

```
%B  Full month name.                            January, February,...
%d  Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal.  01, 02, ..., 31
%Y  Year with century as a decimal number.      2013, 2019 etc.
```

---

`date_return()` returns a string so you can just use it in place of the hardcoded string above:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(date_return(), '%B %d, %Y') + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
```

Comment: But here i am calling a function which will return in August 12, 2022 i cannot explicitly add it

Comment: See my edited answer. The return value of the function call is a string of that format so you can just substitute it into the call.

Answer (score 0):

The Python interpreter is telling you that are trying to concatenate a string (str) with a datetime.timedelta object. Generally, you can only concatenate strings with strings. What you want to do is to convert your timedelta object to a string, then concatenate it with your string.

In your case it will be:

```py
date_return() + str(datetime.timedelta(days=10))
```